# Grep for specific text from kubernetes multiple pods

Tags: logging, kubernetes, grep, kubernetes-pod, wc

I have two pods running for a specific service. I want to get logs related to both the pods and check for specific text.

For that I used ,as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069736/how-do-i-get-logs-from-all-pods-of-a-kubernetes-replication-controller):

`kubectl logs -l app=my-app -c my-app-container --since=25m | grep -i "search-text" |wc -l`

This does not output anything, even though there are matching text for `search-text`

Then tried with `deployments`

`kubectl logs deployment/my-app-deployment -c my-app-container --since=90m  | grep -i "search-text" |wc -l`

How can I search for this specific string in all related pods?

`kubectl logs my-pod-1 -c my-app-container --since=90m  | grep -i "search-text" |wc -l`, this gives the proper count.

References :

[Get all Logs from a specific container in a replica set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851250/get-all-logs-from-a-specific-container-in-a-replica-set)

[how to get logs of deployment from kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518658/how-to-get-logs-of-deployment-from-kubernetes)

Comment: may be check the output of this first: `kubectl logs -l app=my-app -c my-app-container --since=25m`? does it return the expected logs?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Yes, it has output.

Comment: you can use this to get pods for all containers matching the label: `kubectl logs -l app=my-app --all-containers | grep "time" | wc`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia It gives 0 as output

Comment: not sure what could be wrong, check if grep results for any other string or not to make sure the pattern you are looking for do not need escaping with `\\`.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Yes, I had checked with `DEBUG`, I found something interesting. `grep -i "DEBUG" ` shows more records, but when I add `grep "time" | wc -l` it always shows 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228841/discussion-between-krishna-chaurasia-and-sachith-muhandiram).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Nope, still the same

Comment: I see. Have you considered to use a more powerful tool to tail logs like [Stern](https://github.com/stern/stern) or [Kubetail](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail)? They are as easy to use as a simple `kubectl logs` and provide more options from which I see that would satisfy your use case.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor unfortunately, this is production server and this is an emergency requirement for some alerts. Thats why we can not use any other tool.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl logs` is limited to viewing a single pod’s logs at a time. However, you can use the `-l` flag to use a selector (label query) to filter on. For example:

```
kubectl logs -l app=nginx -l app=php
```

Use `-c` flag if you need to see container logs. More supported flags and examples can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs).

When you are able to see the logs from desired Pods/Containers it is time to use `grep` to filter out the output. For example, I got some logs from a Pod:

```
~$ kubectl logs nginx-app-b8b875889-4nn52
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

and I would like to only see lines with the word "configuration", so I execute:

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-app-b8b875889-4nn52 | grep configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
```

or if I would like to count lines with the word "info" than:

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-app-b8b875889-4nn52 | grep info |wc -l
2
```

More details can be found in the [grep manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html). Bear in mind that if you don't specify arguments like `--since=` or `--tail=` and the Pod your are trying to view logs from is running for some longer period of time the results may be misleading.

Normally, I would also suggest to use 3rd party tools like [Stern](https://github.com/stern/stern) or [Kubetail](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail) which are more powerful than simple `kubectl logs` but in your use case combining both:

- `kubectl logs -l`

and:

- `| grep`

is the way to go.

**EDIT:**

Also make sure you are greping from the proper resources. From your question it seems that you run `kubectl logs deployment/my-app-deployment` and than `kubectl logs my-pod-1 -c my-app-container` which does not correspond to the `my-app-deployment` deployment. List all deployments, pods and labels to be confident that you check the right resource. Use:

```
kubectl get deploy,pods --show-labels
```

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram I have made a small edit that might interest you. Please take a look.